# SQL query for day of week in Java EE - HSQLDB vs Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, hsqldb, database-independent

I've got JavaEE app, the main one is working on docker with PostgreSQL,
tests are working with HSQLDB,

In a query I want to check day of the week (to exclude weekends from gathered data)

In Postgres the following works:

```
extract(dow from date) != 0 AND extract(dow from date) != 6
```

When with HSQLDB this results in:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: DOW

For HSQLDB I would need to use:

```
DAYOFWEEK(date) != 1 AND DAYOFWEEK(date) != 7
```

But that of course doesn't work with PostgreSQL:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function dayofweek(date) does not exist

Any idea how to unify this?

I guess, to set the same db-type in persistance.xml resources.xml for tests and app? But I wonder if there is any SQL function I could use for both, without re-editing xml files?

Comment: Another good example on why running tests on a different DBMS then the production one isn't a good idea.

Comment: Could you try the JDBC function escape `{fn DAYOFWEEK(date)}`. In theory all JDBC drivers should unescape to the correct database specific function, but they don't always do.

Comment: BTW: The range of that function escape should be 1..7, with 1 being Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved:**

I used JPQL NamedQuery (I was using NativeQuery) with passed parameter of list of LocalDates (with weekends + holidays),

in query, in WHERE section I've typed:

```
'myDay not in :listOfWeekendsAndHolidays'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just verified Mark's suggestion to use [JDBC escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#1006519) and the following works with both HSQLDB and Postgres:

```
{fn DAYOFWEEK(date)} <> 0 AND {fn DAYOFWEEK(date)} <> 6
```